# How to initialize an iOS app with default data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, persistence

I'm writing an app that needs to access data from a large file every time a button is pushed. I've been reading up on it and the  [apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFAQ.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001802-CJBDBHCB)  says:

"You can create a separate persistent store that contains the default data and include the store as an application resource. When you want to use it, you must either copy the whole store to a suitable location, or copy the objects from the defaults store to an existing store."

Does this sound like the best way to go?

I've created the database with the table I need and put it under "Supporting Files" in Xcode - is this an application resource? Also I'm not sure what it means by "you must either copy the whole store to a suitable location" - is this not it?

Finally, my main question - how do I access the information in the DB in my .m files? Thanks for bearing with me, still very new to this.

Comment: Not sure if you really needed core data by this: ... access data from a large file....?

Answer (score 0):

**Does this sound like the best way to go?**

I believe it depends on what kind of information you want to access and if you need to update this information (add new information, modify it, delete, etc).

If you just want to read the data and do something with it, check out [Property Lists](http://www.appcoda.com/enhance-your-simple-table-app-with-property-list/) and [XML](https://www.raywenderlich.com/725/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml). In case the data is structured somewhat like a relational database and it is necessary to modify it, check out Apple's [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html) framework.

**Is this an application resource?**

Yes, it kind is, don't worry about the nomenclature so much but for more clarification check out Apple's own [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html) about resources.

**Also I'm not sure what it means by "you must either copy the whole store to a suitable location" - is this not it?**

You can load the store from multiple locations (folders, different files, etc), this just means that you should pick the best that suits your application.

Note, the files you import to your project are stored in the application's bundle and you can't (as far as I know) modify them. So, if you choose to include a Core Data store file, you need to copy the store from the bundle to a location of your preference (ex: the documents folder).

**How do I access the information in the DB in my .m files?**

It depends on your pick. As it looks like you're more interested in using Core Data, start by looking at the link I've provided above and searching some tutorials.